# Navigation Menu dropdown hiding in header n content

Tags: html, css, menu, menuitem, submenu

my menu drop down is hiding behind content.i have a storefront child theme.treid too change z index but it scrolls the header.
sample site http://jaipur.onlinewebshop.net/sample-page/
and sample link is under menu item shop.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the CSS property: overflow: hidden!important;

```
.site-header {
border-bottom-color: #f0f0f0;
background-color: #00dbff;
margin-bottom: -2.9em;
**overflow: hidden!important;**
}
```

Comment: Also remove CSS: .site {overflow-x: hidden;}

Comment: I see you live website you didn't remove CSS.

Comment: well i followed what you said but didnt work."Please remove the CSS property: overflow: hidden!important;".i could manage it by editing .content-area, .widget-area margin-top:  -30.11em;  and site-header   margin-bottom: 22.1em;